# Мнемоніка для запам'ятовування планет Сонячої системи

Tags: mnemonic

Син в англомовній школі вивчив наступну мнемонічну фразу для запам'ятовування 8 планет Сонячної системи в порядку від найближчої до Сонця (Меркурій) до найдальшої (Нептун):

My Very Educated Mother Just Served Us Nachos

M = Mercury
V = Venus
E = Earth
M = Mars
J = Jupiter
S = Saturn
U = Uranus
N = Neptune

Коли вважалося, що планет було 9, найпопулярнішою мнемонічною фразою англійською мовою була My Very Educated Mother Just Served Us Nine Pizzas (P = Pluto).

Які є українські аналоги? Чи вчать їх в українських школах, чи це вважається чимось "несерйозним"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Нас учителька вчила так:
**"Маленький Василько З Маленьким Юрком Співали Українські Народні Пісні"**

Ще чула: **"Маючи Великі Здібності Маленький Юрко Співав Українські Народні Пісні"**

Але обидва варіанти втратили актуальність через Плутона.

Як і всі інші, ці мнемонікси обов'язковістю не обтяжені. Все залежить від викладача.

**UPD**. Як зазначив спостережливий і кмітливий **[@Sashaeve](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/326/sashaeve)**,

якщо у будь-якому з двох варіантів прибрати слово `"Пісні"` (що позначало `"Плутон"`), суть фрази майже не втратиться.

Напр. **Маленький Василько З Маленьким Юрком Співали Українські Народні**.

Answer (score 5):

Ми у (російськомовній, а якій же іще) школі запам'ятовували так:

> **МеВеЗеМа ЮСУН**(П) — псевдо-ім'я

Де перше слово кодує назви планет Земної групи, а друге, відповідно, — назви планет групи Юпітера.

І, попри те, що ця мнемоніка іноземного походження, вона цілком підходить до викладання українською.

А після того, як Плутон було «розжалувано» зі списку планет, ця мнемоніка стала ще більш приємною на слух і легшою до запам'ятовування.

У підручниках такого слова я не зустрічав і дуже здивувався б, якби знайшов.

Answer (score 5):

**М**аша **в**избирує **з**орі – **м**онети, **Ю**ра **с**трибає **у** **н**ові **п**ланети (знову ж таки, Плутон ще присутній).